# React Sidebar (Page not found)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-sidebar

Hier ist meine aktuelle Dateistruktur:

```
D:\Projekte\Learning\app\user:
- Ordner: navbar, Seiten
- Datei: page.tsx

D:\Projects\Learning\app\user\navbar:
- Datei: Sidebar.tsx, SidebarPath.tsx

D:\Projects\Learning\app\user\pages:
- Ordner: Server
- Datei: Home.tsx
```

Hier ist der vollständige Code meiner Klassen:

Seite.tsx:

```
"use client";

importiere React von "react";
importiere { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } von "react-router-dom";
import Sidebar aus "./navbar/Sidebar";
import Home aus "./pages/Home";
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Router>
        <div className="flex">
          <Sidebar>
          <div className="w-4/5">
            <Routen>
              <Route path="/user/pages/Home" element={<Home />} />
            </Routen>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>text</button>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Home.tsx:

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="text-center">
      <h1 className="text-center text-3xl">Home</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Sidebar.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { SidebarPath } from "./SidebarPath";

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-52 bg-gray-200 h-screen">
      <nav className="mt-10">
        <ul className="space-y-2">
          {SidebarPath.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={index} className="px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-300">
              <Link to={item.path} className="flex items-center">
                {item.icon}
                <span className="ml-2">{item.title}</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default sidebar;
```

SidebarPath.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import * as AiIcons from "react-icons/ai";

export const SidebarPath = [
  {
    title: "Home",
    path: "/user/pages/Home",
    icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome />,
  },
];
```

Despite my efforts, I continue to get the 404 error "This page could not be found" when trying to reload the http://localhost:3000/user/pages/Home page.

I have already taken the following steps to resolve the problem:
Verifies that the Home.tsx files are in the correct directory.
Updates the paths in the SidebarPath file to make sure they match the actual file paths.
Checks that I am using the latest versions of React, React Router, and Next.js.
Restarted the development server to make sure the changes take effect.
Despite these steps, I continue to get the 404 error. Is there something I may have missed or are there other steps I can take to get the routing to work?

I have tried googling, asking ChatGPT and asking on Discord server but nothing has helped. I hope someone here can help me.

Comment: Please update the code so that your entire question is in English. React, by default creates a Single-Page-Application (SPA), meaning it will load at `http://localhost:3000`. If you wish to have navigation, you could use something like [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main)

Comment: My mistake. I now have the code on Github so that you can better understand it. https://github.com/Jonaskop44/Adminpanel